# Make html select element required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Html form and I need to make the `<select>` element in my form to be required, as of now my script only validates `<input type="text">` elements and ignores the `<select>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.registration-form fieldset:first-child').fadeIn('slow');

$('.registration-form input[type="text"]').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('input-error');
});

// next step
$('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function () {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;

    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });

    if (next_step) {
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    }

});

// previous step
$('.registration-form .btn-previous').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $(this).prev().fadeIn();
    });
});

// submit
$('.registration-form').on('submit', function (e) {

    $(this).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });

});


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an input field required in `HTML5` by using the `required` attribute in with the `<input >` field, like so

**HTML**

```
<form method="#">
  <input id="email" type="email" required >
  <input id="password" type="password" required >
  <select name="select" id="select" required>
     <option value="Select an option" disabled selected></option>
  </select>
</form>
```

You will need to wrap the inputs in a form

**JS**

```
// next step
$('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function () {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;

    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        } else {
            let selectVal = document.querySelector('select').value;
            if (selectVal && selectVal.length >= 1) {
               // passed
               $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
            else {
              // failed
              $(this).addClass('input-error');
              next_step = false;
            }
        }
    });

    if (next_step) {
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Input type="text" fields are being validated by the script I'm using. I need to also validate <select></select> which my script is not doing. I need the setting for validating <select> element in my form

Comment: @Myprepaycellular I've updated my answer with a js code to validate select

Comment: I tried implementing your solution but it still does not validate, I believe i need to add something here """ parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]') """

Comment: The addition I gave is independent of the jQuery. If there is more than one select then you need to use `document.querySelectorAll('select')` then loop through the NodeList

Comment: I implemented the change since I had more than one select field but it's still not validating the select and also all other elements are being set to required even when I input entries in them and click next.

Comment: I think we need to set syntax for select similar to this parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function ()

Comment: then, have you tried `parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], select').each()`?

Comment: No I have not since I'm almost done and need only to fix the <select>

Answer (score 0):

Try `.selectedIndex` property of the select. Your first `<option>` should be empty, then just verify if selectedIndex is other than 0.